# How to add extra columns and override the failed job operation in Larvel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a new bee to laravel, i am trying to use the queues to perform certain tasks.
I am able to create a job and dispatch it, but when a job fails due to exception or some other reason, i want to do add few extra columns and provide more information into failed_jobs table.
The only way i could update the record for newly added columns, if i have the row id of record which is moved to failed jobs table, or i could somehow provide the information to failed method which updates automatically. I did search for this but couldn't find solution.
so going with the first solution, currently i am unable to do so.

I have created a model for failed_jobs to fetch the last record in the failed method, but it does not gives me the last record which is moved from jobs to failed_job instead it gives me n-1 which is the last record before moving the current failed record.

```
$last_insert = MotFailedJobs::select('id')->where('queue','my_queue')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
//update code for newly added columns based on last insert id
```

can any one help me, how can i get the last insert id for the record moved in failed_jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to a failed event on the job, or trigger one yourself on the job. From documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#handling-failed-jobs

```php
class SendShipmentNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;
 
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(OrderShipped $event): void
    {
        // ...
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     */
    public function failed(OrderShipped $event, Throwable $exception): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

another way would be via a global event

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed;
 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{ 
    public function boot()
    {
        Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
            // $event->connectionName
            // $event->job
            // $event->exception
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @kris thank you for this solution. But i am bit confused, is there any other way to do it.?